# 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode' django mails

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to send an email after a form submission using [django-mail-templated](https://github.com/artemrizhov/django-mail-templated).

When I submit my form I get this error :

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'encode'

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
send_mail(
    'autres/ticket_m.tpl', 
    {'user': request.user}, 
    'example@gmail.com ', 
    ['example@domain.ch']
)
```

**ticket_m.tpl**

```
{% extends "mail_templated/base.tpl" %}

{% block subject %}
Hello {{ user }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{{ user }}, this is a plain text message.
{% endblock %}

{% block html %}
{{ user }}, this is an <strong>html</strong> message.
{% endblock %}
```

As you can see I am using django-mail-templated as the documentation so why do I get this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`send_mail`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#send-mail) has a different signature than what you appear to assume. The first argument is the subject, the second is the already rendered message, both as strings:

```
send_mail(
    'subject of your email', 
    render_to_string('autres/ticket_m.tpl', {'user': request.user}),
    'example@gmail.com ', 
    ['example@domain.ch']
)
```

Required parameters as in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/email/#send-mail):

> - subject: A string.
> - message: A string.
> - from_email: A string.
> - recipient_list: A list of strings, each an email address. Each member of recipient_list will see the other recipients in the “To:” field of the email message.

Comment: I know it got out of the scope of my problem but now I'm getting this error : `Reverse for '<HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/">' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []` Do you know what seems to cause this ?

Comment: This is truely out the scope of this question and its comments, but it appears you are pasing a `HttpResponseRedirect` (one of django's Response classes) object to either the `reverse[_lazy]` function or the `url` templatetag.

Comment: Oh okay it has nothing to do with mails so it's all good, thanks !

Comment: I doubt it. Check if there are any `url` tags in your `"mail_templated/base.tpl"` or anything like `reverse(redirect('index'))` in your view.

Comment: Yes there is a redirect(reverse('index')), I'll have to find out why it doesn't work, I'll try to not comment too much on this other issue since it's out of the scope :)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you are assuming that `send_mail` will render a template with the context you provide; but it doesn't know anything about templates, it is expecting a string containing the body of the email. You need to render that separately and pass it to the function:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
body = render_to_string('autres/ticket_m.tpl', {'user': request.user})
send_mail(
    'Subject',
    body, 
    'example@gmail.com ', 
    ['example@domain.ch']
)
```

Note that the first parameter is the subject of the email.